# swift4 selector function without parameters

Tags: ios, swift

In my new project, when i tap a button, it will pop up a menu view from bottom.

[image]

and the code:

```
blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))
```

and the `handleDismiss` function:

```
@objc func handleDismiss(callback:(() -> ())?) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 0
            //......
            }
        }) { (completed: Bool) in
            callback?()
        }
    }
```

then i tap the menu view's `Cancel` cell, call the `handleDismiss` function  with a `callback` parameter . it's working.

```
if item.icon == "close" {
    handleDismiss(callback: {
        print("callback now")
    })
  }
```

but if i tap the black mask view(trigger  `action: #selector(handleDismiss))`), it's error like below:

[image]

does anyone has idea?

Comment: yes because blackview have tap-gesture and required sender object of UIGestureRecognizer with IBAction. so you have to create a new function with UIGestureRecognizer 's sender and call handleDismiss from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When wiring up an action via a `selector` you have to match the expected method signature. Your handler method `handleDismiss` has a closure parameter which is not compatible with what `UITapGestureRecognizer` expects; in this case that's a single gesture recognizer parameter, or no parameter. So you have to add a second method which acts as the tap event listener and forwards the call to the dismiss handler:

```
@objc func didTapDismiss() {
  handleDismiss(callback: nil) // call your dismiss logic from the tap handler
}
```

Your dismiss handler code can stay as it is (you can get rid of `@objc` which is no longer needed though):

```
func handleDismiss(callback:(() -> ())?) {
  ...
```

When hooking up the tap listener, use the new tap handler action:

```
blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapDismiss)))
```

---

A final note: I don't know your exact use case but you might make things overly complicated by using tap gesture recognizers; have you considered to just use `UIButton` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The function to handle a gesture must be defined as shown below.

```
@IBAction func myActionMethod(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)
```

When the UITapGestureRecognizer calls the action function in your controller, it passes the UIGestureRecognizer object as the parameter.
You can't define the action function to take any parameter you want.